# exit status 1 'mySerial' does not name a type

Tags: programming, arduino-nano

I just can't make it work for some reason. I tried `#include <SoftwareSerial.h>` and I tried `#include "SoftwareSerial.h"`. Can someone help me?

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);

uint16_t buf[256];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    buf[i] = (uint16_t)i;
}
  mySerial.begin(4800);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world"); //printLn  L, not I

void loop() {
  Serial.write((uint8_t*)buf, 512);
  if (Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```

Comment: In C and C++ we write executable code **inside functions**. You for some reason placed executable code outside of any functions. This is what triggered the error. What were you trying to achive by that? (In C++ some executable code can be placed outside, but this is not your case)

Answer (score 2):

simple mistake mySerial.begin(4800);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world"); lines was out of void {}

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11);

uint16_t buf[256];

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  while(!Serial);
  for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
    buf[i] = (uint16_t)i;
   mySerial.begin(4800);
  mySerial.println("Hello, world"); //printLn  L, not I 
}


void loop() {
  Serial.write((uint8_t*)buf, 512);
  if (Serial.available()) {
    mySerial.write(Serial.read());
  }
}
```